# How to check if option key is pressed at startup of a mac bash Application

Tags: macos, bash, startup

I got a relatively simple question.

I have a few mac applications that have launchers written in bash. 
I wanted to add a little feature to the launchers, by letting others access a config.app or something else located in /Contents/Resources, when they press the 'option/alt' key at the startup of the app. Kinda like iTunes or iPhoto, where you can access a little options menu.

I don't know how the code should look like when it's purely in bash; i found a few examples that make use of applescript and/or cocoa hooks, but none purely in bash.

Something like: `if 'optionKeyDown'; then open "$WORKDIR/../Resources/config.app"`

Or is this not possible in pure bash at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good solution here: http://lists.apple.com/archives/applescript-users/2009/Sep/msg00374.html

Take the following code:

```
#import <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    unsigned int modifiers = GetCurrentKeyModifiers();

    if (argc == 1)
        printf("%d\n", modifiers);

    else {

        int i, result = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {

            if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "shift"))
                result = result && (modifiers & shiftKey);

            else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "option"))
                result = result && (modifiers & optionKey);

            else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "cmd"))
                result = result && (modifiers & cmdKey);

            else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "control"))
                result = result && (modifiers & controlKey);

            else if (0 == strcmp(argv[i], "capslock"))
                result = result && (modifiers & alphaLock);

        }
        printf("%d\n", result);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Paste it into a file called, e.g. keys.m.

Then build a command line utility like this:

```
$ gcc keys.m -framework Carbon -o keys
```

Put the `keys` executable somewhere in your path, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`, or even just in the same directory as your bash script, then you can call it as e.g. `keys option` and check the returned string for "0" or "1".

Comment: Thanks. 
The executable itself seems to output the specific numbers of the keys pressed tough, like option is 2048.

How would i implement this in bash directly with an if statement?

I tried this, but something seems off:

keys="$WORKDIR/keys"

if [[ 'keys option' == '1' ]]

Comment: @devilhunter: It only returns 2048 for option if you don't pass the `option` parameter, i.e. if you just called it as `keys` rather than `keys option`. Try it from the command line in Terminal to see how it works.